# can't search ___ or ___ 2 field in database, only search the last field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

can't search **_ or _** 2 field in database,
below is my code and I used before in other project, but now if I set like this for search keyword in two field, it only can search the 2nd field, I can't figure why? How to fix this make it work?

Thanks.

```
php
$keyword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);
$sql = "select * from $table where subject or content like '%$keyword%';";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($list = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $id = $list[id];
    $subject = $list[subject];
    $content = $list[content];
}

mysql
id    mediumint(6)    AUTO_INCREMENT  INDEX
subject    text    utf8_unicode_ci
content    longtext    utf8_unicode_ci    PRIMARY UNIQUE INDEX
```

Comment: Oh my good god, why do you have *any* indexes defined on your LONGTEXT `content` field at all, let alone *three* of them?

Comment: but if I click content INDEX in phpMyAdmin to cancel the setting, it will show #1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'content' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: Yeah, you really shouldn't have *any* indexing set on a BLOB/TEXT type field. Maybe FULLTEXT, but that's a whole other bag of cats.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I just creat a  new table in phpmyadmin and it auto set the PRIMARY UNIQUE INDEX. and is this table structure http://imgur.com/veHG2 something wrong?? any advice will be apperciated

Comment: Those indexes generally rank somewhere between useless and counter-productive on a TEXT field and, given what you've posted, they will not have any benefit to your program. Remove any indexes from the `content` field, remove the INDEX from the `id` field, then set the `id` field as your primary key.

Comment: but those icon after I click, not change anything, not remove INDEX or can't change PRIMARY.  or did I miss something?   I already set Privileges Database-specific privileges (Check All)

Comment: and this not work too.. ALTER TABLE  `table` DROP PRIMARY KEY ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) ;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it should be

```
select * 
from   $table
where  subject like '%$keyword%' or 
       content like '%$keyword%'
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

u can use it like that

```
where  subject like '%$keyword1%' or 

        content like '%$keyword2%'
```